# New help with SQL Server select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need help with select statement in SQL Server / T-SQL

My table looks like this:

```
Id (int)  
QuestionId (int)  
GenreId (int)  
QuestionScore (int)
```

I want to select random **N** rows from this table so that maximum number of same GenreId in the result set is less than **X** for all GenreId-s except one. For that one GenreId,   I need row count with that GenreId to be equal to **Y**.

**UPDATE**
I made up this query from suggestions below, it works exactly as i wanted (except for one genre, but thats no problem, let it be this way, ill have 2 queries)

```
select top @N * from
(select Id,GenreId,Rank() over (Partition BY GenreId order by newId()) as Rank,QuestionScore from Questions) t
where t.Rank <= @X
order by newId()
```

now i need to select rows so that average QuestionScore is between 1.7 AND 2.3
how can i do that? i need all columns returned in result set.
thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your request in general seems to be impossible. What if N is 100, X is 5 and there are only 2 genres? What assumptions are you making? And how random should this be? Is it more important to get many different genres? Is it OK if one genre is completely unrepresented in the results.

Comment: It would help to know the version of SQL Server you're using.

Comment: Im using SQL Server 2005. Maximum value of N is 33 and number of Genres is ~50 It is ok if some genres will not be included in result.

Comment: Can anyone help me with updated question?

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server 2005+, use:

```
SELECT TOP (@n) c.*
  FROM (
SELECT a.id,
       a.questionid,
       a.genreid
  FROM (SELECT t.*,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.genreid) AS rank
          FROM TABLE t
         WHERE t.genreid NOT IN (SELECT TOP 1 --ensure only one genre, see order by
                                        t.genreid
                                   FROM TABLE t
                               GROUP BY t.genreid
                                 HAVING COUNT(*) = @y 
                               ORDER BY t.genreid) 
      ) a
 WHERE a.rank < @x
UNION ALL
SELECT b.id,
       b.questionid,
       b.genreid
  FROM TABLE b
 WHERE b.genreid IN (SELECT TOP 1 --ensure only one genre, see order by
                            t.genreid
                       FROM TABLE t
                   GROUP BY t.genreid
                     HAVING COUNT(*) = @y
                   ORDER BY t.genreid ) ) c
```

Comment: I think @y is a different limit for a specific genere,  it's not supposed to be used to find a genre. If it were, it could find more then one, contradicting the question

Comment: @Andomar: The OP states that the genreid that is excluded from the set has to have a row count of *y*.  It's very likely there could be more than one genreid with *y* number of rows - TOP would handle that once we knew more about which of the duplicates would be selected.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can do that with nested subqueries and `top` clauses:

```
select  top (@n) * 
from    (
        -- Retrieve @y rows from the special genre
        -- The prio field is used to ensure all these rows make it inside @n
        select  top (@y) 1 as prio, genreid, questionid
        from    @t
        where   genreid = @the_one

        -- And up to @x rows per non-special genre
        union all
        select  2 as prio, genreid, questionid
        from    (
                select  *
                ,       row_number() over (partition by genreid 
                                           order by newid()) as rownr
                from    @t
                where   genreid <> @the_one
                ) sub
        where rownr < @x
        ) sub2
order by
        prio, newid()
```

Sample data:

```
declare @t table (id int identity, QuestionId int, GenreId int)

insert @t (GenreId, QuestionId) values 
    (1,1),
    (2,1),(2,1),
    (3,1),(3,1),(3,1),
    (4,1),(4,1),(4,1),(4,1),
    (5,1),(5,1),(5,1),(5,1),(5,1)

declare @n int
declare @x int
declare @y int
declare @the_one int

set @n = 7 -- Total rows
set @x = 3 -- With less then 3 per genre
set @y = 3 -- Except three rows from genre @the_one
set @the_one = 3
```

Results in (one example, output differs on each run:

```
prio  genreid  questionid
1     3        1
1     3        3
1     3        2
2     4        1
2     1        1
2     5        1
2     5        4
```